# What does clicking on a comment's time stamp do?

Tags: discussion, comments, design, timestamps

Today I noticed that when I mouse over a time stamp for a comment, the default mouse pointer changes to the little hand with the index finger up, indicating that the time stamp can be clicked on. When you click on it, the page moves so the comment is at the top of the page and it is briefly highlighted orange. Here is an example screenshot of what happens from a current HNQ:

[image: What happens when you click on the time stamp.]

It appears to do the same thing across all SEs. When I hover over the time stamp, it just provides a more specific time. What am I missing here?

Hopefully I haven't been flagging supercat's comment a ton of times of something like that as I've been playing around trying to figure this out.

Comment: This is a common pattern all over the internet.  Learn it once, use it everywhere.

Comment: @Won't Interesting. In all my years of internetting, I've never noticed it. Wonder if it'll be a "you notice it once, you start seeing it everywhere" type thing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is a direct link to the comment itself.

Let's you get a link to put elsewhere - so people can go directly to the comment.

Comment: That makes sense. What that feature ever just a "Share" button after the time stamp similar to questions and answers or is that just a fabricated memory?

Comment: Yeah, the share link is just for questions and answers.